# Java url.openConnection()

Tags: java, jvm

1) How can I send specific request headers whilst a url.openConnection()?

2) Also, how can I, in addition, turn the request to a POST and send post data as well?

3) What document would you recommend to learn further more about url.openConnection() and its possibilities?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you even bother to look around? http://stackoverflow.com/a/2793153/393657

Answer (score 2):

1. `connection.addRequestProperty(headerName, headerValue);`
2. You should call `connection.setRequestMethod("POST");`, then call  `connection.getOutputStream()` and write to this stream content of `POST` request.
3. google: "java http post example" brings tons of documentation. Here is the first one: http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.net/post.html

Comment: Hello, thank you. However, the most important part is missing. How do I select the IP address FROM which this request will be fired? Server has multiple IP addresses bind to it, multiple interfaces. I want to use a specific one for this request. I would really appreciate your help, thank you VERY MUCH!